# how to create zip file without including all of the folders the files came from

Tags: command-line, batch-file, zip

how can I create a zip file without including all of the folders the files came from?

SO I have

```
file1.xml,
file2.xml,
file3.xml,
...
```

and these are all in folder desktop/data/xmlFiles/

When I zip using following command:

```
zip -9 -m -q C:\Users\Desktop\data\xmlFiles\XML.zip C:\Users\Desktop\data\xmlFiles\*.xml
```

This stores the entire path into the XML.zip file.

How do I just include my file1.xml, file2.xml, file3.xml ... inside of my XML.zip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
cd C:\Users\Desktop\data\xmlFiles
zip -9 -m -q XML.zip *.xml
```

Comment: It worked but I had to use pushd. cd didn't work for some reason. thank you @Lucas.

Comment: oh it didn't work after all: zip error: Zip file structure invalid :(

Comment: Do you already have a file called XML.zip?  It sounds like it found a file already there, attempted to add *.xml to it, and found that file was not a valid zip file.

Comment: I do. and I want to be able to replace it @Lucas

Comment: You can try the `-d` option which should _delete entries in zipfile_, but I would just add a `del XML.zip` before the `zip ...` line to remove the old XML.zip before creating a new one.

Comment: When I try to delete it, this is what I get: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"@Lucas

Comment: This is because once I zip the file I use WinSCP to send it to linux machine@Lucas

Comment: And I am trying to automated all of this using task Scheduler, but it is very difficult because winSCP never releases the file after using it

Comment: @Angelina, I have never used winSCP, but i have had great success with putty ssp ([pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html))

Comment: I apparently never exited after using WinSCP.exe so that's what was causing it. I fixed it. I added EXIT command at the end of the executable file that I was using to transfer files. It fixed it. Thank you @Lucas

Comment: @Angelina, if this solved your problem, you should mark it as the answer.